# PHP array of arrays. Checkboxes to be ticked depending on inner array values

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I have arrays of Strings(that are each a combination of numbers "1" to "20") inside **another** array in `PHP`. I want to pre-tick the corresponding checkboxes (1 - 20) for each of my pages (these start at 0 and go on for potentially very many).This way the user can go to a page and see which boxes have been selected before.
 For example: 
`Array [0]` is `{1, 2, 4}` so these checkboxes should be checked when the user arrives at page 0.
 
This is what I have so far to try and get the values of the inner array:

```
foreach ($categoriesArr as $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        foreach ($val as $innerVal) {
            // See which checkboxes are checked.
            if ($innerVal === "1") {
                $cb1 = true;
            } else {
                $cb1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use `<?php if ($cb1) echo "checked" ?>` in the checkbox `HTML` to show it as ticked.
This is ok but it obviously loops through all the arrays and `$cb1` will eventually end up as whatever the last arrays value is. 
Should I introduce yet another array to store each individual pages checkbox values in? I am potentially dealing with thousands of entries so would like to keep any extra assignments to a minimum.

Comment: Off topic but is `$innerVal` a string? Else `$cb1` is always false because of the `===` operator.

Comment: $innerVal is indeed a String sir, question ammended to reflect that

Comment: Could you elaborate on what informations you want to have after the foreach? Checkboxes checked on each page seperatly? Checkboxes checked on all pages combined?

Comment: I want the user to be able to see which checkboxes have been pre-selected for each page, on each page, so page 2 may have different boxes from page 4 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have variable that holds page's index, and then you just include this into each checkbox:
`<?php if(is_array($categoriesArr[$pageIndexVariable]) && $categoriesArr[$pageIndexVariable][$checkboxNameOrIdOrwhatever])` echo "checked" ?>

Comment: Thanks, I realise how simple this is now. I think I was making life hard for myself but I can finish this now :)